# How to add fonts to mkv container with ffmpeg?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

I have a video in an mkv container that has subtitles that need additional fonts, I have the required fonts in the .ttf format.

How can I add them the the mkv container?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attach a single font:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -attach font.ttf -metadata:s:t mimetype=application/x-truetype-font output.mkv
```

Attach two fonts and XML file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -attach font.ttf -attach anotherfont.ttf -attach file.xml -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -metadata:s:t:1 mimetype=application/x-truetype-font -metadata:s:t:2 mimetype=text/xml output.mkv
```

- `-map 0`. Selects **all** streams. Otherwise default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior selects 1 stream per stream type. See [`-map` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) and [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).
- `-c copy` Enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode to only re-mux and avoids re-encoding.
- `-attach` Adds an attachment to the output file.
- `-metadata mimetype=...` Sets the mimetype metadata. You must set a mimetype for each attachment for Matroska output. The two examples above assume `input.mkv` has no attachments.

If you get error:

```
Attachment stream has no mimetype tag and it cannot be deduced from the codec id.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Then you either forgot to set the mimetype or your [stream specifier](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers) is incorrect in the `-metadata` option.

Comment: I indeed got the error "Attachment stream 4 has no mimetype tag and it cannot be deduced from the codec id. Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument" because I also want to attach an XML file. So what is the command to declare multiple metadata and what is the mimetype of an XML file, and where do you find the index of the output stream?

Comment: @guestnbxd1 See updated answer. XML mimetype is `text/xml` for human readable XML. Otherwise use `application/xml`. Refer to [RFC 3023](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3023#section-3), section 3. Index of output streams is shown in the console output under `Stream mapping:`

Comment: I finally get it! for each attachment I add I have to increase the number in "-metadata:s:t:NUMBER" starting from 0 for it to work. 

But why can't we start from the number after the last stream file has? For example, the video already has  
Stream #0:0 
Stream #0:1 
Stream #0:3 
So to add 2 attachments it would be -metadata:s:t:4 then -metadata:s:t:5 instead of starting from 0.

And If I understood correctly s stands for stream and t stands for attachment.

Thanks @llogan, your answer solved my problem.

Comment: @guestnbxd1 You can do it that way too. For example assume output stream `#4` is a TTF attachment. And it is the only attachment. You can either do `-metadata:s:t` (set metadata for all a`t`tachments), `-metadata:s:t:0` (set metadata for the first attachment [ffmpeg starts counting from 0]), or `-metadata:s:4`(set metadata for output stream 4, regardless of stream type).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 
I just noticed that the XML file that I added to display the chapters doesn't do anything. Is there a reason for that?.

Comment: @guestnbxd1 I don't know. It can be asked as a new question.